# Assert object equivalence by value

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, fluent-assertions

I'm sure i'm missing the obvious...

Say we have:

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    public int AnotherProp { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var a = new MyObject { SomeProp = "hello", AnotherProp = 9 };
    var b = new MyObject { SomeProp = "hello" };
    var c = new MyObject { AnotherProp = 9 };
    var d = new MyObject { SomeProp = "hello", AnotherProp = 9 };
}
```

What is the correct assertion to check that all of the properties match (e.g. `a` and `d` would return true, but all other combinations would return false?

At the moment, i'm doing equivalency checks, but have to do it in both directions? e.g.

```cs
    a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(d);
    d.Should().BeEquivalentTo(a);
```

Forgive me if this is clearly defined in the docs... I can't find it :/

Comment: Don't you mean comparing `a` and `d` (not `b`) should return `true`?

Comment: Haha- I do, absolutely- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    public int AnotherProp { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as MyObject;

        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return other.SomeProp == SomeProp &&
               other.AnotherProp == AnotherProp;
    }
}
```

and then just do

```
Assert.True(a.Equals(d));
```

I do not know if there is any other way of doing this.

Comment: If you override `Equals()`, do not forget to also override `GetHashcode()`

Comment: It would be tedious to implement Equals methods for all classes (and impossible for some external ones). I may as well just check all of the props in the test separately if I'm going to do that.
Can you see any issues/drawbacks with my current approach?

Comment: @LeeTickett No I think your approach is fine, the only other way I could think of was this one.

Comment: How about using a `record` instead, then Equals and GetHashcode are overridden for you

Comment: Can you elaborate @CaiusJard

Comment: @LeeTickett https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

Answer (score 0):

Check the fluent assertions documentation [here](https://fluentassertions.com/numerictypes/). It recommends implementing IComparable interface for what you need.

Also, if you check this:

```
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);
```

You wouldnt/shouldnt check the oposite direction:

```
    b.Should().BeEquivalentTo(a);
```

Cause thats the same!

Comment: Try it for yourself... You do need to check both. The first assertion will only check that all properties in `b` match those in `a`... but it doesn't care if `a` has a bunch of extra properties. The second assertion then handles that...

Comment: Not sure if you're right. If A and B are the same type MyObject than the IComparable.CompareTo() would return false if a.AnotherProp = 1 and b.AnotherProp = null.

Comment: *has a bunch of extra properties* - how do two instances of the same class realize a situation where one of the instances has "more properties" than the other? In `var b = new MyObject { SomeProp = "hello" };` the `AnotherProp` doesn't cease to exist just because you didn't mention it; it just has a value that is `default` for its type

Comment: You're quite right. I've confused myself. I was definitely having a problem where I think I had to do this... perhaps it was something to do with anonymous types. 
I'll take another look and try and clarify or post a new question. Thank you

Comment: OK I figured out what I was trying to do/why!!! It was comparing anonymous objects. I will have another search then if needed post a new question.